# A linear algebra question

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

$V$ is a vector space with finite dimension. Let $f_1, \ldots,f_m\in\operatorname{End}(V)$ be linear maps of $V$ to itself. Suppose that $V=\ker(f_1)+\ldots+\ker(f_m)$. Show that there are $g_1, \ldots ,g_m\in\operatorname{End}(V)$ such that $\ker(g_1\cdot f_1+\ldots+g_m\cdot f_m)=V$ and at least one of the $g_k$ is non-zero.

Could you help me to prove this problem?

Comment: I think I miss something. What about all the g's equal zero?

Comment: I'm having additional trouble understanding the question. In what sense do you mean "$f_1,\cdots, f_m$ are **the** linear map of $V$ to itself " ? Are they special or is it an imprecision? Do you mean that *each* of the $f_i$-s is a linear map $V\to V$, or that they are the coordinates of a single linear map $F:V\to V$ defined by $F(v):=(f_1(v),\cdots, f_m(v))$, i.e. that each $f_i$ is an element of $V^*$ ?

Comment: To Mr Sassatelli. Thank you! It means each of the $f_i$ is a linear map.

Comment: To Mr Schnabel. Thank you ! But it isn't mentioned. How about at least one $g_i$ are not zero? Could this be proved?

Comment: Sure, because at least one of the $f_i$ is not invertible then you can built $ker(g_i)=Im(f_i)\neq V$.

Comment: @YanDong I edited the question.

Comment: I gave more details in an answer.

Answer (score 1):

There exists at least one $f_i$ such that Im$(f_i)$ has a basis 
$$\{v_1,v_2,...,v_k\},$$
where $k$ is strictly smaller than the dimension of $V$.
We can take a basis for $V$ now
$$\{v_1,v_2,...,v_k,u_{k+1},...,u_n\}.$$
And define
$$g_i(v_j)=0,\quad g_i(u_j)=u_j.$$
All the other g's are zero.

Comment: To Mr Schnabel and Mr Sassatelli. Thanks for the answer both of you! Let me think about it and then give you a reply. Thank you!

Comment: To Mr Schnabel, "where $k$ is strictly smaller than the dimension of $V$" is that means the $k$ is the smallest dimension of $Im(f_i)$? If it is, why do we choose this $f_i$ to construct a non-trivial $g_i$? Does the other $f_i$ has any probelm?

Comment: @YanDong , $k$ is the dimension of $f_i$. Since ker$(f_i)\neq 0$, the image of $f_i$ has dimension smaller then the dimension of $V$. Some of the other $f_j$ might have a trivial kernel.